# Blowing up ideal of denominators to find the difference of effective Cartier divisors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety and $D$ is a Cartier divisor on it. Fulton argues in his *Intersection theory*, that if we let $I$ be the ideal of denominators (locally in $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, we have $I=\{a\in A:ad\in A\}$ where $d$ be the local equation of $D$) of $D$. Consider the blowing up $f:\mathrm{Bl}_IX\to X$, then he claim that $f^*D=C-E$ where $E$
is the exceptional divisor and $C$ is an effective Cartier divisor! I don't know how to deduce this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of intuition I have about this, I'll try to come up with a more formal approach: Any Cartier divisor $D$ has an associated Weil divisor $D^w$, which decomposes as a sum of principal divisors $D^w = \sum n_i D_i$. By grouping together the $D_i$ with positive (respectively negative) coefficients, we can decompose
$$D^w = D^+ - D^-,$$
where both $D^+$ and $D^-$ are "effective" Weil divisors (meaning only positive multiplicities).
However the trouble is  that $D^+$ and $D^-$ need not be Cartier divisors. I think that blowing up the ideal of divisors should be like "blowing up $D^-$", making it a Cartier divisor.

(Note that I'm not sure if it formally makes sense to blow-up $D^-$, since that is not a subscheme a-priori.)